# Save and restore tabs in gnome terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

We have GNOME Terminal 3.14.3. This version does not support `--save-config` option. Is there any other way to do so in this version? How else can one save and restore tabs? What version of gnome terminal will allow me to do so?

The error is:

```
Option "--save-config" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean that you want to save your current terminal profile (but I lack the reputation to ask this as a comment). If that's the case:

You may try going to your Terminal Preferences. Next to Profiles, click the "+" next to "Profiles" to save the current configuration (in this example, called `MYPROFILE`).

[image]

Then type

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=MYPROFILE
```

There is a also the `--window-with-profile` option, which makes a new terminal window.

I am using GNOME Terminal 3.32.1 on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: This doesn't seem to save multiple tabs, or the names of those tabs. I think question this wants the same thing I do - the ability to restore tabs like restoring tabs in Chrome after closing and re-opening (like after a restart).